# having trouble using variable variables in PHP

Tags: php, variables, echo

i'm doing this code from the book and i can't seem to get it to work

```
<html>
<head> <h3> <u> PHP tutorials  </u> </h3> </head>
<body>

<?php

$Texas = "large";
$RhodeIsland = "small";

$statement = "Texas";
echo "$statement is $($statement)<br>";

$statement = "RhodeIsland";
echo "$statement is $($statement)<br>";

?>
</body>
</html>
```

this is the output i keep getting:

Texas is $(Texas)

RhodeIsland is $(RhodeIsland)

instead of:

Texas is large

RhodeIsland is small

Comment: Try to avoid use of this (variable variable) if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax is : `${$variable_name}`, not `$($variable_name)`. You need to change your code to:

```
$statement = "Texas";
echo "$statement is ${$statement}<br>";
```

See the [PHP manual documentation on *Variable Variables*](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) for more information.

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/142323)

Answer (score 0):

There you go:

```
 <?php

    $Texas = "large";
    $RhodeIsland = "small";

    $statement = "Texas";
    echo $statement." is ".${$statement}."<br />";

    $statement = "RhodeIsland";
    echo $statement." is ".${$statement} ."<br />";

    ?>
```

Comment: The OP was asking how to do it with variable variables, specifically. I assume he's trying to learn how it works :)

Answer (score 0):

You should be using curly brackets instead of parentheses.

```
$statement = "RhodeIsland";
echo "$statement is ${$statement}<br>";
```

PHP documentation on the subject is here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Answer (score 0):

this works :)

```
    <?php
    $Texas = "large";
    $RhodeIsland = "small";

    $statement = "Texas";
    echo $statement." is ".$$statement."<br>";

    $statement = "RhodeIsland";
    echo $statement." is ".$$statement."<br>";
```

---